# How can I redirect once facebook like button is clicked?

Tags: facebook, redirect, facebook-like

Basically, here is an idea:
I am starting a daily blog, and in order to gain access to sunday's posts, the user needs to share the site.
I have figured out how to redirect once someone presses the +1 button, and how to redirect once someone tweets, but I have yet to figure out how to redirect after a facebook like.
If anyone can help with this, I'll be very thankful.

For the record, I plan on doing this as whitehat-edly as possible. Basically, the post will say that I'm trying to gain popularity for the site, that I could really use some shares, I'll point out that they get six posts a week without asking for anything, and I'll tell them that I'm fine with them deleting the post if they really don't want to share it.

One other thing, I don't really care if they post it on facebook or not. Like, the code doesn't need to check their facebook page to make sure it worked. I just want it so that when they click the button, it posts, and redirects them. The page won't be hidden, if someone had the direct URL they could get to it without sharing. I just want it to be simple, as I'm an amateur, but I also want to use this to get more traffic and a more engaged audience.

Thanks in advance,
Liam

Comment: There were no yes or no questions asked. I'm sorry if I've done something wrong that is stopping you from helping me.

Comment: "If anyone can help with this". Question.

Answer (score 7):

While what you are doing is not a good idea at all, redirecting after clicking the "Like" button can be handled with the Facebook javascript event, [`edge.create`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        location.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/post/id';
    }
);
```

Comment: may i have an example where to add this answer to my html page? Do i need a <script> tag for it? and im using iframe like button is it ok?

Comment: @CheongDMunPong, yes this is a JS code. Moreover, this works with the XFBML and HTML5 version as per the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/)