# Redirect after a user clicked a facebook like button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like

I have a facebook tab with an iframe application and within that tab there is a facebook like button to have a second capability to like the facebook page. It is an ordinary facebook like button iframe.

Is there a possibility to redirect the user when it clicks the button? I tried it the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: '<my app id>', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1500 });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
            function(response) {
                alert('like!');
            }
        );
    };

    //Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
              '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
```

But this doesn't work. Is there a way or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the like button functioning properly on its own?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I redirect once facebook like button is clicked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886102/how-can-i-redirect-once-facebook-like-button-is-clicked)

Answer (score 1):

I just tested the following code and it works as expected

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<fb:like href="http://yoururlto.like" send="false" width="450" show_faces="false" font=""></fb:like>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({appId: 'YOUR_APP_ID', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
        FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 1500 });
        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
            function(response) {
                alert('like!');
                // put redirect code here eg
                window.location = "http://www.mysite.com/redirected.html"; 
            }
        );
    };

    //Load the SDK asynchronously
    (function() {
        var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
            e.src = document.location.protocol +
              '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
            document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

How does it compare to your own page?

Comment: The like button is not implemented in fbml but as an iframe.

Comment: Sorry. If you must use iFrame then the create.edge event will not be triggered.

Comment: The FB-Tags would only work in FBML-Tabs or is the fb javascript library replacing them by html?

Comment: Facebook JavaScript will render XFBML for use in iFrames and websites. Try my code example above.