# Facebook like button redirect?

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, modx

Is it possible to add a like button feature to your Facebook page which re-directs to another page and offers the user a free ebook?

I'm creating a website within MODx which runs via PHP.

Comment: Try looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924371/redirect-after-a-user-clicked-a-facebook-like-button) to see if it will help you out.  It would be a client side issue with the redirect, so more of a javascript thing than a PHP one ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For only like button:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div id="fblike">
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="site name" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="100" data-show-faces="false"></div>
</div>
```

**Redirect after clicking Like button:**

This can be handled with the Facebook javascript event, [`edge.create`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/):

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        location.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/post/id';
    }
);
```

may this help you.

Comment: only like button he don't want. he want when someone click on that like button then download start

Comment: @SumitBijvani i changed my answer....

Comment: @AdvaitAmin Cool thanks for that. But how do I hide the Facebook comment that appears?

Comment: may i know where do i add the FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        location.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/post/id';
    }
);