# Facebook like button redirect even after liked

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook, facebook-like

I am using the edge create function i got from this question
[Facebook like button redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15427045/facebook-like-button-redirect)

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        location.href = 'http://yourdomain.com/post/id';
    }
);
```

So the code is working properly - page will be liked and redirect to another page,

But seems like it only does this function when the user haven't liked the page

When the user already liked the page, the button will be "in a liked state" and I still want the user to redirect when they click the like button

Is there a function for this still?

Or how can I check if the user already liked the page, maybe in this way i can display a button to have a redirect onclick for them

Comment: It's probably to do with the selector used for the subscribe event. The class of the button likely changes. Inspect a *liked* button and compare, then bind to `onClick` for a selector matching the *liked* state to redirect?

Comment: Like gating is not allowed

Comment: Had you followed the link to the documentation in that other question’s answer … then you could have discovered that there’s also an `edge.remove` event.