# Increment PHP variable on facebook like on my website

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I redirect once facebook like button is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6886102/how-can-i-redirect-once-facebook-like-button-is-clicked)

I have many facebook's fan pages like button on my website, I want to increment a php variable $counter when someone likes any particular fan page on my web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a Facebook APP and then use the Javscript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

After importing the SDK, you should subscribe to the following event `edge.create` using this code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
    }
);
```

This will be executed when a user presses the one of the like buttons. As you can see the `response` variable holds the "*liked*" url, you should pass this via AJAX call to a PHP script and if the URL is a valid URL of your pages you can increment your PHP variable.

You can see all Facebook events here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/